# MVC Razor 3 RC syntax: Bug or user error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'd like to think this is obvious, but before I submit a bug report, I want to know that I'm not doing it wrong. I have this view using ASP.NET MVC3 RC, with Razor:

```
<div class="miniProfile">
    Joined: @FormatTime(Model.Joined)<br />
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Location)) {
        Location: @Model.Location<br />
    }
    Posts: @Model.PostCount<br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Full Profile", "ViewProfile", new { id = Model.UserID }, new { target = "_blank" }) | 
    @Html.ActionLink("Send Private Message", "SendNew", "PrivateMessages", new { id = Model.UserID }) | 
    @Html.ActionLink("Send E-mail", "Send", "Email", new { id = Model.UserID })
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Web)) {
        | <a href="@Model.Web" target="_blank">Visit user Web site: @Model.Web</a>
    }
</div>
```

It chokes at "Location" and at the pipe in the last conditional. If I insert some <text> tags, it works like this:

```
<div class="miniProfile">
    Joined: @FormatTime(Model.Joined)<br />
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Location)) {
        <text>Location: </text>@Model.Location<br />
    }
    Posts: @Model.PostCount<br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Full Profile", "ViewProfile", new { id = Model.UserID }, new { target = "_blank" }) | 
    @Html.ActionLink("Send Private Message", "SendNew", "PrivateMessages", new { id = Model.UserID }) | 
    @Html.ActionLink("Send E-mail", "Send", "Email", new { id = Model.UserID })
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Web)) {
        <text>| </text><a href="@Model.Web" target="_blank">Visit user Web site: @Model.Web</a>
    }
</div>
```

Despite some trial and error, I can't figure out what I'm doing that is naughty. Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your markup should be as follows

```
<div class="miniProfile">
  Joined: @FormatTime(Model.Joined)<br />
  @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Location)) {
    <text>Location: @Model.Location<br /></text>
  }
  Posts: @Model.PostCount<br />
  @Html.ActionLink("Full Profile", "ViewProfile", new { id = Model.UserID }, new { target = "_blank" }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Send Private Message", "SendNew", "PrivateMessages", new { id = Model.UserID }) |
  @Html.ActionLink("Send E-mail", "Send", "Email", new { id = Model.UserID })
  @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Web)) {
    <text>| <a href="@Model.Web" target="_blank">Visit user Web site: @Model.Web</a></text>
  }
</div>
```

When you have an `@if` statement, anything after the curlys is still considered to be 'code' so you need to break out of it by either using a `<text>` tag or the `@:` syntax.

The reason for this behavior is that frequently you will have some sort of tag nested inside the conditional anyway, in which case things just work:

```
@if(condition) {
    <div>Some content</div>
}
```

The `<text>` tag is there for those case when you don't want the contents of the conditional to be wrapped in any tags.

Comment: Perfect... that's the explanation I was looking for. I guess it wasn't clear to me that code needs an "end signal" and that a new line doesn't do that. We're very excited about the RC over here in STO, by the way. :)

Comment: ScottGu just posted a pretty complete explanation of this whole concept at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can't have just plain text content inside of a code block, the Razor engine can't figure out if it's code or markup.  That's what the `<text>` tags are there, to remove the ambiguity.  Are you saying that the `<text>` tags make it work (that's the answer, there's nothing more to be done), or that it still doesn't work with the `<text>` tags (try wrapping the whole `if` block in the `<text>` tag)?